# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I've browsed through a couple of questions but I couldn't find any help.
By the way this is the first time I'm asking a question here so I might not do it the right way. Anyway, the following line is causing me the problem

```
/* cursorPps defined above */
document.getElementById("cursorPps").innerHTML = cursorPps;
```

The `cursorPps` variable is already defined. Can someone point out what other possible stuff could have caused this error?

Edit: By the way the problem is that it is not updating the value on HTML, although the value of the variable changes.

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Potato Clicker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="left">
<img id="potato-img" onClick="potatoClick(clickPower)" src="stockvault-potatoes107220.jpg" width="300" height="300">
<br>
<div id="mainDisplay">
<span id="potatoes">0</span> <br> potatoes
<br>
<br>
Producing <span id="pps">0</span> potatoes per second
<br>
</div>
Cursors: <span id="cursors">0</span>
</div>

<div id="middle">
<div id="buildings" onClick="buyCursor()"> &nbsp; Buy Cursor &nbsp; </div>
</div>


<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
//variables

var potatoes = 0;   //potatoes
var clickPower = 1; //potatoes gained per click
var pps = 0;        //potatoes per second
var cursors = 0;    //cursors
var cursorCost;     //cost of cursor
var cursorPps = 0;  //total cursor potatoes per second
var cursorBuy;      //cursor buy button


//functions

function potatoClick(number) {

potatoes = potatoes + number;
document.getElementById("potatoes").innerHTML = potatoes;

}

function buyCursor() {

var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.2,cursors));
if (potatoes >= cursorCost) {
pps = pps - cursorPps;
cursors = cursors + 1;
potatoes = potatoes - cursorCost;
cursorPps = cursorPps + 1;
pps = pps + cursorPps;
document.getElementById("potatoes").innerHTML = potatoes;
document.getElementById("cursors").innerHTML = cursors;
document.getElementById("cursorPps").innerHTML = cursorPps;
document.getElementById("pps").innerHTML = pps;
}
else {
alert("Not enough potatoes!")
}
var nextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.2,cursors));       
document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost; 
}

window.setInterval(function () {

if (pps > 0) {

potatoClick(pps);

}

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Do you have an element with an `id` of `cursorPps` in your DOM?  It would be case sensitive.

Comment: Please share the HTML code with us.

Comment: Either you have no element with the id of "cursorPps" or You are trying to read the element before it is rendered to the page. Plenty of duplicates, too lazy to find. Answer, use onload or document ready or put the scripts at the bottom of the page, not in the head.

Comment: yeah i did give me a moment I'll post my full code

Comment: @epascarello I put it at the bottom, just before ending the <body> tag

Comment: *"The `cursorPps` variable is already defined."* It doesn't matter that the variable is defined. That's not the issue. The issue is that you don't have an element in your HTML with  `id="cursorPps"`

Comment: Oh ok I see.. I think I know how to fix it already.

Comment: Thanks @cookiemonster I solved it. So how do I close this question

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't have a delete button, you can either accept (click the check) one of the answers below if you found them helpful, or flag it for a moderator to delete it for you.

Comment: well your comment helped me find the answer so um i should delete this?

Comment: If you don't have a delete button, you can flag it for a moderator and explain the issue. I would normally tell you to click the check next to one of the answers below, but I don't think either answer is very good.

Comment: Yeah it's your comment that led me to the answer so there really isn't a proper answer.. And I don't think this would be useful to other users.. So um how do I flag it?

Comment: Isn't there a `flag` link next to the `edit` link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that

- You have an element has that ID
- The element IS on the page before that Javascript is run
- You bind the execution of your JS to an event (follow-up from previous) that happens after the element is on the page
- The cursorPps variable has been populated

Here's a simple codepen that demonstrates a way to do it http://codepen.io/leopic/pen/wDtIB

Comment: sorry i'm a noob um what do you mean by the 3rd and 4th points?

Comment: Your third point isn't the issue since the code runs in response to a click event. I don't know what you're getting at by the fourth point.

Answer (score 2):

---

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

---

- > *You have an element with that ID*

  ```
  var length = document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv').length;
  if(length > 0) {
      // This element exists in the DOM tree
  }
  ```
- > *You bind the execution of your JS to an event (follow-up from previous) that happens after the element is on the page*

  ```
  <body>
      <div id="myDiv"></div>
      <script>
          var length = document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv').length;
          console.log(length);
      </script>
  </body>
  ```
- > *The cursorPps variable has been populated*

  ```
  if(cursorPps != undefined)
  ```